# Renaming Columns in an SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to rename the columns in the results of a `SELECT` expression.  Of course, the following doesn't work:

```
SELECT * AS foobar_* FROM `foobar`
```

As I'm new to SQL, I think I'm just missing a concept, tool, or keyword that would lead to the answer.  A hint in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for a generic way to do this, and MySQL-specific techniques are absolutely fine.

In short, I'm writing a tool that "exports" the results of MySQL queries to Google Spreadsheets (via the Google Data API).  Some queries are joins, so to make columns unique I wanted to prefix all column names with their respective table names.

Comment: `SELECT col1 As Foo, col2 As Bar FROM foobar`. By the way: Don't use "SELECT*" in a SQL query. 
    Unnecessary columns may get fetched that will add expense to the data retrieval time.
    The database engine cannot utilize the benefit of "Covered Index" and hence the query performs slowly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Updated my question; I actually need to retrieve all columns in my case; but your tip is duly noted.

Comment: Looked around for an answer for a while. Thanks @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can alias the column names one by one, like so

```
SELECT col1 as `MyNameForCol1`, col2 as `MyNameForCol2` 
FROM `foobar`
```

**Edit** You can access `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` directly to mangle a new alias like so. However, how you fit this into a query is beyond my MySql skills :(

```
select CONCAT('Foobar_', COLUMN_NAME)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'Foobar'
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting for justice, since answer is identical to Joe's. Updated the question though; I need a generic way of doing this...

Comment: Aliases are very useful IMO.

Answer (score 11):

you have to rename each column

```
SELECT col1 as MyCol1,
       col2 as MyCol2,
 .......
 FROM `foobar`
```

Comment: Thanks.  Updated my question though, as I need a generic way to do this.  I guess my last resort is generating a list of column names in PHP code...

Answer (score 2):

```
select column1 as xyz,
      column2 as pqr,
.....

from TableName;
```